# Laravel - Get The SUM of multiple withCount()

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am looking for the Eloquent, or raw sql, to get the sums of two of my `->withCount`. I need to be able to do this **without** having to `->get()` the records, it needs to be implemented using Eloquent, not laravels Collection methods.

I have the following:

```
$owners = User::active()
     ->where(function($q){
         $q->whereHas('primaryContractOwner')
         ->orWhereHas('primaryVendorOwner');
     })
     ->withCount([
         'primaryContractOwner',
         'primaryVendorOwner'
     ]);
```

I need to get the sum of `primary_contract_owner` count and `primary_vendor_owner` count. I tried the following but I am getting `primary_contract_owner_count` column not found

```
// This one throws the error
$owners = User::active()
     ->where(function($q){
         $q->whereHas('primaryContractOwner')
         ->orWhereHas('primaryVendorOwner');
     })
     ->withCount([
         'primaryContractOwner',
         'primaryVendorOwner'
     ])
     ->select(['user.*', DB::raw('primary_contract_owner_count + primary_vendor_owner')]);
```

Comment: Why do you need the sum in the query?

Answer (score 1):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

I believe your counts will be called `primaryContractOwner_count` and `primaryVendorOwner_count`. You can run the query without the DB::raw part to check.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the collection method `reduce` as below

```
$owners->reduce(function($carry,$item){
  return $carry+$item->primaryContractOwner_counter;
},0);
```

for more please check the reduce documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-reduce